# linear congruent generator in haskell

Tags: haskell

This is a very simple linear-congruent pseudo-random number generator. It works fine when I seed it, but I want to make it so that it self-seeds with every produced number. Problem is that I don't know how to do that in Haskell where the notion of variables does not exist. I can feed the produced number recursively, but then my result would be a list of integers instead of a single number.

```
linCongGen :: Int -> Int
linCongGen seed = ((2*seed) + 3) `mod` 100
```

Comment: Simple solution: ```linCongGen seed = let x = ((2*seed) + 3) `mod` 100 in x : linCongGen x```, with `linCongGen :: Int -> [Int]` then since Haskell is lazy, everytime you need the next number, you can get it from the head of the list. The correct solution would use a state monad though... No easy way out - you are asking for a function that returns different output even if you give it the same input.

Comment: thta is exactly what I am asking, yes. A function that returns different output with same input every time. You got it.

Comment: Haskell doesn't let you do that. That is the point of functions in Haskell - they always return the same output given the same input. You can tiptoe around the problem using a state monad.

Comment: @Alec: no need to use direct recursion: [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:iterate) is exactly for this pattern in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'll summarize the comments a bit more meaningfully. The simplest solution is, like you observed, an infinite list of the sequence of generated elements. Then, every time you want to get a new number, pop off the head of that list.

```
linCongGen :: Integral a => a -> [a]
linCongGen = iterate $ \x -> ((2*x) + 3) `mod` 100
```

That said, here is a solution (which I do not agree with), but which does what I think you want. For mutable state, we usually use [`IORef`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-IORef.html), which is sort of like a reference or pointer. Here is the code. Please read the disclaimer afterwards though.

```
import Data.IORef
import System.IO.Unsafe

seed :: IORef Int
seed = unsafePerformIO $ newIORef 71

linCongGen :: IO Int
linCongGen = do previous <- readIORef seed
                modifyIORef' seed $ \x -> ((2*x) + 3) `mod` 100
                return previous
```

And here is a sample usage printing out the first hundred numbers generated: `main = replicateM_ 100 $ getRandom >>= print` (you'll need to have `Control.Monad` imported too for `replicateM_`).

#### DISCLAIMER

This is a bit of a hacky approach described [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Top_level_mutable_state). As the link says "Maybe the need for global mutable state is a symptom of bad design." The link also has a good description of a more intelligent workaround. Making an `IORef` is an inherently `IO` operation, and we really shouldn't be using `unsafePerformIO` on it. If you find yourself fighting Haskell in this way, it's because Haskell was designed to get in your way when you are doing things you shouldn't.

That said, I find comfort in knowing that this approach is also the one using in [System.Random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.3/docs/System-Random.html) (the standard random number module) to define the initial seed ([check out the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.0.0.3/docs/src/System-Random.html#theStdGen)).